# Rails change route url to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have this url working now on my Rails 4.2 app - https://example.org/causes/help-family What do I need to do to change the url's to look like this -  https://example.org/help-family without the "causes" controller showing up in the route?
https://example.org/causes should still continue to list all the causes.

This is what part of my routes file looks like.

```
  resources :causes, only: [:new, :create, :index, :show] do
    get :thankyou
    resources :donations, only: [:new, :create, :show ]
  end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where you defined route for `help-family`? Please post that code.

Comment: "help-family" is a vanity url and is the cause title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
resources :causes, path: '/', only: [:new, :create, :show] do
  get :thankyou
  get :index, path: 'causes', on: :collection
  resources :donations, only: [:new, :create, :show ]
end
```

This is assuming you only want to keep the 'causes' in the path for the index page.

Comment: What to do for those two or three causes which have been public already with the link /causes/help-family? how to redirect them to /help-family? Thanks

Comment: Can't you just change the links to have the path `/help-family?` instead of '/causes/help-family?'

Comment: I can change it on our facebook posts but It has already been shared on other people's facebook and website to include the /causes/ in the url.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
  get '/help-family', to: "causes#help-family"
```

Comment: I have several causes and it is not a good design to add a route for each cause. Don't you agree?

Comment: Rails has powerful support for routing arbitrary URLs to actions. Here, you don't get groups of routes automatically generated by resourceful routing. Instead, you set up each route within your application separately.

While you should usually use resourceful routing, there are still many places where the simpler routing is more appropriate. There's no need to try to shoehorn every last piece of your application into a resourceful framework if that's not a good fit      see it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html